# How can i use Ajax Jquery and return View?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have an Ajax Jquery function which sends Values (location and parameters) to an IActionresult which does a search in a Database and returns a new View with the right Objectdata of a Model.

Breakpoints are showing me that it enters the Actionresult and pass the parameters correct and it runs the return View, but it doesn't return the View. It just do nothing.

Does the Jquery Ajax expect some other data type ?

In Browser Console i can see that the Post Method ist done.

Thanks for your help.

**Index.cshtml**

```cs
var LatPosition;
var LongPosition;

const successCallback = (position) => {
    console.log(position);
    LongPosition = position.coords.longitude;
    LatPosition = position.coords.latitude;
    console.log(LatPosition);
}

const errorCallback = (error) => {
    console.error(error);
}
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback);

function sendAjaxRequest(element, urlToSend) {
    var clickedButton = element;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: urlToSend,
        dataType: "json",
        data: { 
            LongPosition: LongPosition, 
            LatPosition: LatPosition, 
            id: clickedButton.val(), 
            takeValue: $("#TabakName").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        failure: function (errMsg) {
            alert(errMsg);
        }
    });

    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#button_1').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            sendAjaxRequest($(this), '@Url.Action("Tabakvalidierung","Home")');
        });
    });
 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#TabakName").autocomplete({
     source: '@Url.Action("Search", "Tabaksuche")',

    });
});
```

**HomeController.cs**

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Tabakvalidierung(
    string takeValue, 
    string LongPosition, 
    string LatPosition) 
{
    return  View("Shopliste", shopDatens); //returning View with right object
}
```

Comment: datatype you should be expecting from server is html, not json. Check out what `dataType` and `contentType` mean.  With MVC it's possible to return a Partial View from your controller and display the resulting Html using jQuery. But this only makes sense if you want to replace part of the page. If you want to return View (an entire Html page), the question is why are you using Ajax in first place? You could just post to the page using jQuery.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes i figured out whats dataType and contentType means. Changed it then it gives me the html of the View. I wanted to use this way because i have location api which saves the variables in javascript.  I will try only using Jquery. Right now i try to use hidden form and save js var into hidden form and pass it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your ajax to this:

```
$.ajax(
            {
               
                  url: urlToSend,
                 data: { 
            LongPosition: LongPosition, 
            LatPosition: LatPosition, 
            id: clickedButton.val(), 
            takeValue: $("#TabakName").val()
        },
                
                type: "POST",
              
                success: function (result) {
                    $(div).html(result);

// div is  Id of <div>  where you have to show you partial view
                
                },
                error: function (xhr, exception) {
                    ........
                }
            });
```

and change your controller to this:

````
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Tabakvalidierung(
    string takeValue, 
    string LongPosition, 
    string LatPosition) 
{
    return  PartialView("Shopliste", shopDatens); 

// return partial View, if you use View it will be returned with the whole Layout
}  
```
````

Comment: Thank you very much Sergey. I already did a workaround with hidden forms. But i will try your solution later :)